# I am bias for the popular,Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> What I do all the time,
>
> Is what you are doing right now.
>
> Only thing you need are hints and,
>
> All I want are 20 answers.
>
> Not always right, Neither are you.
>
> We are same, no? You breathe and I don't.
>
> Although I am bias for the popular,
>
> I am one too.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok just kind of random answer, but i think the solution is

> Akinator (the game)

Explanation:

what i do all the time, is what you are doing right now.

> we are guessing

Only thing you need are hints and, all i want is 20 answers

> akinator the game usually asks for hints on the person we are thinking, and he needs us to answer for him to guess (but the 20 part makes me confuse, so im not too sure on this on)

not always right, neither are you.

> sometimes akinator guess the guess wrong

We are same, no?You breath and I don't.

> he is a game, so he doesnt breath.

Althouh I am bias for the popular, I am one too.

> He only knows the popular people, and the game itself is popular.

Hope i got it right :P

Comment: Correct. The original akinator only asks 20 questions so.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps it is:

> The game [20 Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20Q)?

What I do all the time,

Is what you are doing right now.

> i.e., looking for answer, which is a user of stack.exchange is presumably doing.

Only thing you need are hints and,

All I want are 20 answers.

> A person wants hints to find the answer to a question, whereas 20Q AI depends on 20 yes/no/maybe answers to guess what the user is thinking.

Not always right, Neither are you.

> Check.

We are same, no? You breathe and I don't.

> Check.

Although I am bias for the popular,

> It tends to guess popular guesses.

I am one too.

> It's somewhat popular itself.